# Changing font size of code in StackExchange

Tags: css, font-size, userscripts

Can the blocks of code on StackExchange posts ({} icon the toolbar) be reduced or increased in size by changing the font size, or any other means?

Comment: Should this be on meta perhaps? I mean, with the newly added css and userscript tags I guess it could make sense as a development question. But aside from that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a userscript, you can:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Stack Exchange Code Formatting CSS
// @include  http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include  http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include  http://*.serverfault.com/*
// @include  http://*.superuser.com/*
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle ( "code,pre { font-size:14px !important; white-space:pre-wrap }");
```

The default font size is 13px. Applying the font-size to code is what works. In my example, I wanted to word-wrap the (pre) text so I made it simpler by applying the two properties to both.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is slightly larger than normal.  But still *very* hackish.  And probably won't work for multi-line blocks

## `enter code here`

```
`code to highlight`
===================
```

You can achieve the same thing with straight HTML tags if desired, as shown below.  A list of allowed HTML tags can be found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites

## `this is a test of
multiline code`

```
<h1>
<code>this is a test of
multiline code</code>
</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to say font size cannot be changed but you can make it **BOLD** or *ITALICS* to emphasize.

Comment: How is this done _in code blocks_?